# jQuery Spinner not working, shows a normal textbox instead

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am using [jQuery Spinner](http://jqueryui.com/spinner/) to show a textbox with increment/decrement options.

For now, I have written very basic code to create the spinner.

#### HTML

```
<input id="spinner" name="value">
```

#### jQuery

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $(".spinner").spinner();
    });
</script>
```

[Here’s a jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/NY4mE/)

After rendering on the page, it shows a plain textbox, and in the console, I get these errors:

> - ReferenceError: `jQuery` is not defined
>
>   ```
>   })( jQuery );
>   ```
> - TypeError: `$(...).spinner` is not a function
>
>   ```
>   $("#spinner").spinner();
>   ```

Have I forgotten to call some extra jQuery, or something else?

Comment: Please leave your post either as you posted it or as it was edited; don't keep rolling it back between the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't selected a jquery library.You need to select appropriate Jquery framework for you .

**If your other frameworks are using jquery you must include the jquery library befoore including other libraries**

[image]

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#spinner").spinner();
 });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/samithaHewawasam/xF3pG/)

Comment: OP adding it as an external resource in his fiddle

Comment: you need to select the Jquery library

Comment: @YuriyGalanter but he added it after the Jquery UI libraries

Comment: @samitha in his Fiddle yes, but not in his copy/pasted code. Which works as it is: http://jsfiddle.net/NY4mE/3/

Comment: @AT-UID now your library structure is ok :)

Comment: If the library structure is fine, then why still its not working for my fiddle.. that was my question :-) This is my fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/NY4mE/

Comment: see in your external resource jquery-ui.js,jquery-ui.css,jquery-1.9.1.js.it's wrong.It should be 
jquery-1.9.1.js ,jquery-ui.js,jquery-ui.css

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in you're indeed correctly referencing jQuery and before jQueryUI. In that case it works:

**jsfiddle.net/NY4mE/1/**  -- using jsFiddle references

OR

**jsfiddle.net/NY4mE/3/**  -- using direct links like in your own sample